# PC has a mind of it's own

Tags: power-management

When I put my PC into standby, sometimes it randomly awakes, scaring me and waking me up. What could be causing this. No it is not my mouse moving, it can only be powered back on by the power button. It's really strange.

Comment: It could be haunted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be network activity. A lot of "default" standby configurations are set to resume on network activity.

Answer (score 0):

Does it then proceed to turn off again? If the computer is set to hibernate after a given amount of time, it will wake itself from standby, then put itself into hibernation. This is normal. Another possibility is that a scheduled task is waking it up on a timer - does it wake up at the same time every time, or seemingly randomly?

Comment: It's completely random, I don't use hibernate. It might do it tonight it might not, it happens 1 - 2 times per month.

Comment: The strange thing is that it is a new pc, and my old pc was doing the exact same thing. I might have some ghosts or stuff haha.